# How can I create an app that uses Microsoft Azure Active Directory authentication in React & ASP.NET Core MVC web app?

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

How or is there an example of a Reactjs app that uses Microsoft Azure AD authentication ?

I have tried the ASP.NET Core MVC web app in Visual Studio 2022 as this gives the option to use Azure AD authentication when creating the project.

Comment: I assume you have found the following guide?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-react-spa-app
I explains quite clearly what has to be done.
Basically, you need to use msal-react for the frontend, and the rest should be very similar to the MVC sample.
If you need more help, I suggest asking more specific questions.

Comment: I have had a look and gone through this example, yes. But the page when rendered is just blank ? I added the files it mentioned through visual studio by opening the folder

Comment: do you think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66362840/react-azure-ad-returned-blank-page/66383018#66383018) help you? and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763252/azure-authentication-audience-validation-failed) contains a sample link

Comment: yes they are helpful

Comment: thanks and you can feel free to update here if you met any other problems